# Converting speech to text

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have already gone through the sample code present in the Android SDK. It tells that you should have voice recognition APK in your device. I tried a lot but could not find any apk. Can anyone suggest which voice recognition APK to install to get voice recognition. My device is a Samsung Galaxy.

Comment: Have you checked the market? https://market.android.com/details?id=com.marvin.espeak&feature=search_result  https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.tts&feature=search_result

Comment: A common question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253740/speech-to-text-recognizer-not-found

Answer (score 2):

Update:

According to [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html), [Google Voice Search](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch) is what you actually need.

> The Android SDK makes it easy to integrate speech input directly into your own application—just copy and paste from this [sample application](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html) to get started. Android is an open platform, so your application can potentially make use of any speech recognition service on the device that's registered to receive a [RecognizerIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html). Google's Voice Search application, which is pre-installed on many Android devices, responds to a RecognizerIntent by displaying the "Speak now" dialog and streaming audio to Google's servers—the same servers used when a user taps the microphone button on the search widget or the voice-enabled keyboard. (You can check if Voice Search is installed in Settings ➝ Applications ➝ Manage applications.)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the sample of STT without problems. How they said previously, you have to download it from the Market.

Regards