# emulator.exe -help-audio-in on Windows produces "unknown option: -help-audio-in"

Tags: android, android-emulator

The [emulator documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) says:

```
  -audio-in <backend>   Use the specified audio-input backend.
```

It also says that

```
  -help-<option>    Print help for a specific startup option.
```

Which means that **-help-audio-in** should list available backends.

But when I type "emulator.exe -help-audio-in" I receive:

```
  unknown option: -help-audio-in
  please use -help for a list of valid topics
```

Well, when I type ""emulator.exe -help" I receive the same information as in the documentation:

```
  -help-<option>    Print options-specific help.
```

This is a catch 22 situation... How do I get the list of audio "backends" for the emulator in Windows?

Comment: How about using `-help-all`. Mind you, the emulator.exe I have installed has no `-audio-in` option at all.

Comment: @Martin -help-all is one of the first things I tried. Mine doesn't have -audio-in either. The documentation is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself: There isn't any `-help-audio-in` because [the emulator doesn't have an audioInput to hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472370/why-is-it-impossible-to-use-the-speech-recorder-on-the-android-emulator/5487839#5487839).