# How to use JellyBean Voice typing off-line from notification?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I found something similar here
[Voice to text on Android in offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734030/voice-to-text-on-android-in-offline-mode)
and in some other post, but cannot find any specific documentation about offline voice typing of JellyBean. Also tried on Google groups but with no fortune.

What I'd like to do is to tap onto a notification bar and start listening for speech (even off-line), then use this speech to launch some action or activity.

Thanks for attention and for help.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893788/use-offline-voice-to-text-in-android-4-1-jelly-bean-from-my-application