# Offline speech to text

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I use online google speech to text in my application. How can i change it to  offline? I saw it in another app and i know it is possible.
My online speech to text code:

```
if(isConnected()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

`isconnect()` is a method for test connection

Comment: you will get better idea  here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734030/voice-to-text-on-android-in-offline-mode

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline Speech Recognition In Android (JellyBean)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616994/offline-speech-recognition-in-android-jellybean)